# Best way to display last modified time

Tags: javascript, php, timestamp, timezone

Server: CentOS, Apache, PHP 7.6

I want to display the last modified time on my webpage.

Now I use:

```
<?php $lastmodified = filemtime("index.php"); ?>
Last modified on <?php echo date("Y/m/d", $lastmodified);?> at <?php echo date("H:i", $lastmodified); ?>
```

However, this displays the date in the serverTime in **UTC**. How would I do this to change all dates(*if I use more*) to the client time (*preferably client side via JS*)?

No JQuery please.

[Convert date to another timezone in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10087819/convert-date-to-another-timezone-in-javascript) 
Does not explain how to set it to the client time automatically, do the change for all possible timestamps, uses a full string, is not split like my date time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert date to another timezone in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10087819/convert-date-to-another-timezone-in-javascript)

Comment: @KingRichard not fully